# Why is html-tidy forcing my styles onto one line?

Tags: html, css, htmltidy

[html-tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/)  insists on minifying my style block into a single line. So this:

```
<style>
p { background-color: red; } 
#first {border: 2px solid blue} 
</style>
```

gets tidied into this:

```
<style>p { background-color: red; } #first {border: 2px solid blue}</style>
```

I want to keep my `<style>` block readable, so I'd take almost any variation as long as it treats `<style>` as a block level element, but I don't see any way to force that. The closest option I can see is [new-blocklevel-tags](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/#teaching-tidy-about-new-tags), which doesn't have any impact and doesn't make sense as an option anyway.

How do I stop html-tidy from minifying CSS blocks inside of style tags?

Comment: It's standard minification of styles...looks normal to me.

Comment: Okay, but I want readable styles. I don't want them minified.

Comment: Hmm...I've not used this but what I think you are looking for is the `indent-attributes` setting. Look in the Documentation for "How Do I Control the Output Layout?" http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/

Comment: `indent-attributes` isn't it -- that puts attributes on their own line, but the inner text of a style block isn't attributes.

Answer (score 4):

What you call *minifying* is actually removal of indenting. Minifying would mean the complete removal of all spaces, tabs and line breaks from your code, outputting it into one line, eventually compressing all your `CSS` in one file and all `JavaScript` in another.

> **Tidy** is not capable of preserving the original indenting of the markup from the input it receives. That’s because **Tidy** starts by building a clean parse tree from the input, and that parse tree doesn’t contain any information about the original indenting. **Tidy** then pretty-prints the parse tree using the current config settings. Trying to preserve the original indenting from the input would interact badly with the repair operations needed to build a clean parse tree, and would considerably complicate the code.

Complete [documentation here](http://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/).

If you want to keep your indenting, stop using **Tidy**.

> **Response to proposed change by Amanda**: I do not agree *"if you want A, don't do B"* is a hostile phrase construction and *"If you want A, consider not doing B"* should be used instead. For me, the second construct has more hostility, since it is a common structure for ironic comments. I don't want that. When I advise my very own kid, with the best intentions, not to put his hand on the stove if he doesn't want to get burns, I don't say *"consider not putting your hand on the stove"*. I say: *"If you don't want to get burns, don't put your hand on the stove."* [Informative. Friendly. Not hostile.]